# Symfony 2 get list of logged users

Tags: symfony

I am writing some aplication in symfony 2. I need to get list of users who are logged in aplication.

Comment: Save the status (logged/not logged) in your database.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. For my project, a logged in user is who clicked any internal link in the last lets's say, 10 minutes. I could use the session data as I store it in PDO, but it seems a bit tricky to deserialize it every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can...

- Capture the event "onRequest" and store the user_id a time stamp on your database last time this happened. (this updates every time the user clicks a link on your site)
- Make your users send heartbeats via AJAX to your server (easy with jQuery) and store the user_id a time stamp on your database last time this happened. (this updates at known intervals)
- Capture the event "onSecurityInteractiveLogin" and save the time stamp on your database,delete it when they log out (many users never explicitly log out)